# jquery append variable if variable is not empty

Tags: jquery, variables, append

I have several variables in my code :

```
var     titre = bloc_movie_parent.attr("titre"),
    director = bloc_movie_parent.attr("director"),
    prod = bloc_movie_parent.attr("prod"),
    agency = bloc_movie_parent.attr("agency");
```

using this variables i'm building a div using a for each function, and inside this div I have spans that should show but only if the variable exists.

here is my code :

```
        $(".bloc_movie[type='"+ type + "']").each(function(){

            var titre = $(this).attr("titre"),
            director = $(this).attr("director"),
            prod = $(this).attr("prod"),
            agency = $(this).attr("agency"),
            hash = $(this).children('a').attr("href");

            $(".caption_slideshow").append('<div class="bloc_movie"><div class="legende"><div class="titre_caption">'+ titre +'</div><div><span class="initial_director">D/ </span>'+ director +'</div><div><span class="initial_prod">P/ </span>'+ prod +'</div><div><span class="initial_agency">A/ </span>'+ agency +'</div></div></div>');});
```

it works fine.

but sometimes my variable is empty. And when the variable is empty, I want the span to be hidden.
for example if "director" is empty, I want the "initial_director" span to be hidden. same for "prod" with "initial_prod" span & "agency" with "initial_agency".

I can't find a way of doing it inside the append function.

can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: which variable do you mean when "my variable is empty " ?  and which span do you want to hide explain please

Comment: what about appending them one by one so that you can check them individually before each append

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam for example if "director" is empty, I want the "initial_director" span to be hidden. same for "prod" with "initial_prod" span & "agency" with "initial_agency".

Comment: @Matt I can't append them individually because my divs are built after an onclick function, they are not built on the document.ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first define css class called `.display-none{ display:none;}`
then the main idea is

```
if(!director){$('.initial_director').addClass("display-none")}
```

one way of doing it like this adding always a class of display-none concatinated with the value of you variable like this "display-none"+director
here we have two cases the first is empty then the result is display-none which will hide your div 
the second case will have a value so the result would be display-nonevalue which doesn't add any styles

```
<div><span class="initial_prod display-none"+prod+"\"">P/ </span>'+ prod +'</div>
```

Comment: it's not working as its not looping my for each function. If one of my agency var is empty, then all the span are getting the "disply-none" class

Comment: nice trick ! I had to adapt the code a bit but it works like a charm now ! thanks a lot

Comment: @mmdwc my pleasure :)